# "The statement is witnessed"

Tags: terminology, mathematics, logic

> The derivability of a given statement can be justified by exhibiting a derivation tree [...] For example, if
>
> [ some definitions ]
>
> then the derivability of **the statement**
>
> ```
> if t then false else false --> if u then false else false
> ```
>
> **is witnessed** by the following derivation tree:

<sup>(*Types and Programming Languages* by Benjamin C. Pierce)</sup>

Does *witnessed* here means the same as *is justified* from above?

More examples from the same book:

> Indeed, the derivation trees witnessing evaluation statements will always have this slender form: since no evaluation rule has more than one premise, there is no way to construct a branching derivation tree.

And

> In the simple type system we are dealing with in this chapter, every term
>   has a single type (if it has any type at all), and there is always just one derivation tree witnessing this fact.

Comment: I really wish you had picked a different example, because I'm hung up on its redundancy. (There is no reason for a such a construction if the conclusion will always be false. Just state an axiom: false.) It's making it difficult for me to place the word contextually. Also, *witnessed* is not a word that would normally be used here. Things are witnessed by conscious beings—not by "derivation trees."

Comment: @JasonBassford I've added two more examples from the same book

Comment: @Jason Bassford  You are wrong about this: Things are witnessed by conscious beings—not by "derivation trees."  The Cambridge Guide to English Usage, for example, is full of sentences like these: Stopless acronyms/initialisms are normal in the world of computing, witness ASCII, CD-ROM etc. Imperial expressions of length, height and depth vary between singular and plural, witness six foot ﬁve versus six feet ﬁve inches as the height of the local giant.

Comment: @MvLog In your example, *witness ASCII, CD-ROM etc.* is a declaration for the unstated **you** (the reader) to witness something. It's no different than the sentence *Stop!*. I guarantee, it cannot be interpreted as having the ASCII, CD-ROM, or whatever do any witnessing.

Comment: @Jason Bassford  Of course, nobogy takes it literally. But there are much more of that kind: _This old auditorium has witnessed many ceremonies. Recent years have witnessed the collapse of the steel industry. The industry is witnessing a gradual decline in sales._

Comment: @MvLog Idiomatic usage is quite different from syntactical composition that sticks things together that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the tree can not justify the statement, because the tree is in fact derived from the statement (so the justification would involve cyclical logic). Instead, the tree seems to **depict** or **visualize [the structure of the statement]**.

> “Indeed, the derivation trees **depicting** evaluation statements...”